# how to use a file to input a list of vararible in the SQL or sqsh?

Tags: c++, sql-server, c++11, sqsh

I am very new to SQL, I want either integrate the SQL to my c++ code or use c++ output file as an input variable for SQL.

for example i have a query:

```
use data_set1;
select a.cluster, b.pig, b.PDBgi, b.PDBaccession, a.Seqstar, a.Seqstp
from data_set1..clusterPDBpig a 
join pig2PDBgi_acc b
ON a.pig = b.pig where b.PDBaccession = '& 2Y69S'
```

In which the b.PDBaccession is a 500-1000 list of data, I could put them in a vector in c++ code or an output file...How do I integrate SQL query here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up [SQL Table Value Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You can create a user-defined table type parameter like:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AccessionData] AS TABLE(
    [ValueToUse] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ValueToUse] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Then in your SQL code do something like:

```
SELECT a.cluster, b.pig, b.PDBgi, b.PDBaccession, a.Seqstar, a.Seqstp
from clusterPDBpig a
    INNER JOIN pig2PDBgi_acc b on (a.pig = b.pig)
    INNER JOIN @InputData I on (I.PDBaccession = b.PDBaccession)
```

Where @InputData is of type `AccessionData`

The following links provide a bit of information:

http://www.christian-etter.de/?tag=table-valued-parameter

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/pchandraker/passing-table-valued-parameter-to-stored-procedu-part-1/